# trying to change string -> int

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use javascript to change a `string` to an `int`.

```
var intVal = gSpread1.Text * 1;
```

I want `intVal`'s Type to be `int`.

I can get an int value, if `gSpread1.Text` is smaller than 1000.

But if `gSpread1.Text` is larger than 1000, `intVal` returns `NaN`

What is the correct way to use `ParseInt` to ensure that it always returns an `int` value?

Comment: It should work, you'll have to debug and inspect the value that is generating `NaN`...

Comment: Thank you,  Now I catch the reason.
gSpread1.Text  return   with comma (,)

if gSpread1.Text is  1,234  convert to int is not working...  
I really thank you everybody

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Did you try `intVal = parseInt(gSpread1.Text, 10);`

The 10 is called the radix, and indicate the numeral system to use.

**UPDATE:** There is as well a useful shortcut using the `+` symbol.
eg: `+gSpread1.Text` will convert the string to a number. And will return an `integer` or a `float` depending on the string value.

Comment: Good answer - beware parseInt without a radix, because "09" is not a number (no 9 in octal, which is what the 0 prefix represents)

Answer (score 2):

There is no int type in JavaScript. Only number. parseInt is fine if you have a non-decimal number, or you might have trailing garbage on the string like "5asdkfkasdk". But for the common case, when you know your string is only decimal digits, I prefer to use the Number() constructor. It looks more elegant and it's more familiar to C and Python programmers who do a lot of casting.

```
var numericValue = Number("100000");
var numericValue2 = parseInt("100000", 10);
```

These yield the same result of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

**[See how to convert correctly even big numbers.](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/type_convert.html)**

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
var intVal = parseInt("100000");
alert(intVal);
```

Perhaps post your non-working code? The issue might lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your string contains int you can use just one +

```
var n = "455";
n = +n; // now n is integer
```